# Storing mysqli_query into multidimensional php array and utilizing that array as input to highcharts

Tags: php, highcharts, dynamic-arrays

I have a question on saving mysqli_fetch_array into multidimensional php array,I have month and amount as data, ex January-12345.0987,February-87654.3456 etc, I am able to get the data from database and able to store it as two different arrays, but I would like to store it in single one and then I want to use that array to send input to highcharts. Can any one please suggest me, below is the code I used for storing the retrieved data into two different arrays

```
$month=array();
$amount=array();
$i=0;
while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{

   //echo 'inside while loop';
   $month[$i]=$user_data['month'];
   $amount[$i]=$user_data['monthavg'];
   $i++;
   //$month[$i][$i]=$user_data['month']['monthavg'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I should either use a **two dimensional array** (the boring way)

```
$records = mysqli_fetch_all($data);

// Access array of attributes of the first row
var_dump($records[0]);

// Access attribute 'month' of first row
var_dump($records[0]['month']);

// Access attribute 'monthavg' of first row
var_dump($records[0]['monthavg']);
```

or **objects** (the cool way):

```
$records = array();
while($record = mysqli_fetch_object($data))
{
    $actualData[] = $record;
}

// Access array of attributes of the first row
var_dump($records[0]);

// Access attribute 'month' of first row
var_dump($records[0]->month);

// Access attribute 'month' of first row
var_dump($records[0]->monthavg);
```

Then write your JSON or CSV response for your highchart JavaScript app:

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $records);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: Hello ZombieHunter, Can you tell me more clearly, as per my example please ?

Comment: @Satya: This basically is the implementation. I don't see any way to make it clearer. This site is about giving support/pointing in the right direction, not the final implementation. That's your job.

Comment: I tried it, I implemented in my way but I am getting illegal offset

Comment: I have tried in another way, I have fixed that, Thanks for your help once again @ZombieHunter

Answer (score 0):

I recommned you to prepare correct array structure in the php, then use json_encode(). In the javascript use $.getJSON() and load your data. As a result you avoid csv / loading files and parsing it again.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, that is what I am trying to do, I dont know how to establish correct php array surcture for multidimensional arrays in php. If you have any idea can you let me know please ?